Cookie is being cached in server components
I'm using Next Js 14, I'm storing user info in cookies and reading at server components using cookies method from next/headers.
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import ClientComponent from './components'

async function ServerComponent() {
  const allCookies= cookies();
  const user = allCookies.get("user")?.value

  console.log(user);


  return <ClientComponent user={user} />;
}

export default ServerComponent; 

I'm updating these cookies on user sign-in. The problem is If I'm navigating to a page using Link from next/link, the page seems to cache like it contains user info of prev user who was logged in. But if I a do hard refresh on a page it works fine.
I want updated data from cookies on every request. I've tried dynamic="force-dynamic" & noStore from next/cache but none of them is working.
Thanks...
